# Bitcoin core wallet, uncofirmed transaction

Tags: wallet

After 3 days I have this status of my sent transaction:

```
Status: 0/unconfirmed, in memory pool
Date: 08-Feb-21 18:49
To: bcx 33GnCWPGvzEXKSiRFYtZzgv4WTahiZzE5q
Debit: -0.01274861 BTC
Transaction fee: -0.00000880 BTC
Net amount: -0.01275741 BTC
Transaction ID: d286c58ccb57ff47cdfce40e75457f44a27d0a7e063f6116c0fea4033aaf4ae9
Transaction total size: 223 bytes
Transaction virtual size: 142 bytes
Output index: 0
```

What can I do?

Comment: Which wallet do you use? You should be able to RBF it or do CPFP.

Comment: I use bitcoin core v 0.20.1

Comment: Can you do `bumpfee d286c58ccb57ff47cdfce40e75457f44a27d0a7e063f6116c0fea4033aaf4ae9 '{"fee_rate": 0.0005}"` in the console

Comment: Have just canceled transaction with -zapwallettxes